# Gnucash extension to generate interest entries

Tags: gnucash

I often find myself manually entering interest (and according tax) entries for savings accounts in gnucash. Is there a plugin or extension available where I can enter the initial value, the interval and the interest (and tax rate) as well as the run time and the extension automatically generates these entries?

*Offtopic: If no such thing is available: I'd like to write one. Does anyone know whether sample plugins exist for Gnucash or if good documentation is available?*

Answer (score 4):

What GnuCash does is that when you reconcile the statement, it asks you for the interest for the period, and adds it then. Works great for me.